# Can a Neo4j embedded instance be the master in a HA cluster?

Tags: neo4j, cluster-computing, tinkerpop

We're running a Neo4j embedded instance (1.9.5) through TinkerPop Blueprints (2.5.0-SNAPSHOT). Is it possible to make the embedded instance the master in a HA cluster involving Neo4j servers and/or other embedded instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Neo4j instance in a cluster can be master unless it is configured with `ha.slave_only=true`. Embedded and server mode share exactly the same capabilities with respect to clustering.

In case of embedded HA, you need to instantiate your `GraphDatabaseService` instance using http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j-ha/stable/apidocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory.html and pass in the config options.

It's even possible to mix embedded and server instances in a cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this example may help others that find this question:

https://github.com/Jotschi/neo4j-ha-example/tree/master

The example project shows how to setup neo4j embedded in HA mode.